# Casting a multidimensional array to a multidimensional array of it's superclass in c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, casting

so my question is, why is it not allowed, to cast B*** to A*** in this case?
When i manually cast arr to (A**) this code works fine.

```
static const int N = 2;

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() {
    }
    virtual void bla() {
        cout << 'A' << endl;
    }
};

class B: public A {
public:
    ~B() {
    }
    void bla() {
        cout << 'B' << endl;
    }
};

void callBla(A** arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        arr[i]->bla();
    }
}

int main() {
    B** arr = new B*[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        arr[i] = new B[N];
    }
    callBla(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

I couldn't find anything about this case yet, thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: Why not use vectors? Then your code doesn't leak memory.

Comment: hey yeah thanks it does leak memory indeed :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not typesafe; you could do

```
void callBla(A** arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        arr[i] = new A;
    }
}
```

and then your array of `B*` wouldn't be an array of `B*` any more.

or even

```
void callBla(A** arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        *arr[i] = A();
    }
}
```

and then none of your `B`s would be `B`s any more.

Comment: @user3277430 No. A pointer-to-pointer-to-derived can't be converted to a pointer-to-pointer-to-base, ever.